# Pass sheets to the BeforeSheet event Laravel Excel

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

Is it possible to pass the $sheets to the BeforeSheet event? If yes, how? I've tried it but the $sheets returns empty array but when dd the $sheets in the BeforeWriting event I got all the sheets.

```
<?php

namespace Modules\CustomerTransactionSummaries\Exports;

class AccountabilityMultiSheetExport implements WithEvents
{
    use Exportable, RegistersEventListeners;

    protected $dateFrom, $dateTo, $customers, $farm;

    public function __construct(string $dateFrom, string $dateTo, array $customers, Model $farm)
    {
        $this->dateFrom = $dateFrom;
        $this->dateTo = $dateTo;
        $this->customers = $customers;
        $this->farm = $farm;
    }

    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        $sheets = [];

        return [
            BeforeWriting::class => function (BeforeWriting $event) use (&$sheets) {
                $templateFile = new LocalTemporaryFile(storage_path('app/utilities/accountability.xlsx'));
                $event->writer->reopen($templateFile, \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XLSX);

                // * Pass the $sheets to the BeforeSheet
                $sheets = $event->writer->getSheetNames();

                foreach ($sheets as $key => $value) {
                    $event->writer->getSheetByIndex($key)->export($event->getConcernable());
                }

                return $event->getWriter();
            },
            BeforeSheet::class => function (BeforeSheet $excel) use (&$sheets) {
                $sheet = $excel->sheet;

                $summary = new Summaries($this->dateFrom, $this->dateTo, $this->customers, $this->farm);
                $summary->printExcel($sheet->getTitle(), $sheet);
            },
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to pass the variable around, since you can access the underlying `Spreadsheet` class from both events.

Also, the event functions are closures and their results do not get used. (essentially they are `void`), so that return statement shouldn't do anything.

You should be able to access the `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet` class from the `BeforeSheet` event as well.

```php
return [
    BeforeWriting::class => function (BeforeWriting $event) {
        ...
        $sheets = $event->writer->getSheetNames();
        ...
    },
    BeforeSheet::class => function (BeforeSheet $event) {
        ...
        $sheets = $event->sheet->getParent()->getSheetNames();
        ...
    }
];
```

The laravel-excel documentation briefly goes over this:

| Event name | Payload |
| --- | --- |
| `BeforeExport` | `$event->writer` : `Maatwebsite\Excel\Writer` |
| `BeforeWriting` | `$event->writer` : `Maatwebsite\Excel\Writer` |
| `BeforeSheet` | `$event->sheet` : `Maatwebsite\Excel\Sheet` |
| `AfterSheet` | `$event->sheet` : `Maatwebsite\Excel\Sheet` |

These two classes, `Maatwebsite\Excel\Sheet` and `Maatwebsite\Excel\Writer` use the trait [`Maatwebsite\Excel\DelegatedMacroable`](https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel/blob/3.1/src/DelegatedMacroable.php) to ***delegate*** function calls to their underlying phpspreadsheet classes.

- The `Writer`'s delegate class is `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet`.
- The `Sheet`'s delegate class is `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet`.

As it happens, the `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet` class has a method ([`getParent()`](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Worksheet/Worksheet.php#L840)) that returns the underlying `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet` class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I followed your code but I only got one sheet ("Worksheet") in the BeforeSheet event but in the BeforeWriting event, all the sheets in my excel are retrieved.

Comment: Perhaps the aftersheet event is fired multiple times?